# Calculated value not saved in the database

Tags: php, yii

I have this code and it appears that the value is not stored in the database. Here's my code:

```
echo $form->labelEx($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces',array('label'=>'Total Quantity')); 
echo $model->Quantity_In_Pieces = $model->Quantity * $model->Hold;      
echo $form->textField($model->'Quantity_In_Pieces');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the value in your *rendering* code. This calculation should also be done in the code that receives input from the form, before that input is saved to the database.

Comment: then how will I code it in view? is it like this?    echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('Quantity_In_Pieces')); 
 echo $model->Quantity * $model->Hold;           echo CHtml::encode($data->Quantity_In_Pieces);                                                                     sorry i'm really new in yii

Comment: Forget about the view! The view should not be modifying the model, that's a crude violation of data separation. Perform the multiplication in the controller.

Comment: will i make a new function in the controller or will i insert it somewhere on the codes?

Comment: Logic like this which modifies and calculates data should be on the controller or model depending on the situation. In your's it's the controller.

Answer (score 0):

DCoders answer above is a spot on point. But the reason it's not in the database is because your not saving it. It should however show the new value in that rendered text box.

To save the model you need to call the `save()` function on it after making your changes to its values. This is best done in controller code, so it is kept separate from the view presentation code.

If your struggling with this concept then I suggest reading one of the best guides for a framework I've seen:

[Yii Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc)

Just have a read through some of the "Fundamentals" sections to get a grasp of how the MVC structure works. Then if you need specific help with something ask here or on the [Yii Forums](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/)

Comment: will I put it on _form? (my model was just generated)